# How to make this line of code work?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, angularfire2

```
  var relative = af.database.object('users/user75ECZOiNtxZwYoezaXmYA9YwPm53', { preserveSnapshot: true });
  relative.subscribe(
    snapshot => {
      this.usedBasicProfile = snapshot;
    }
  );
  console.log(this.usedBasicProfile);  //the value is undefined, how to make this work?
```

what I want to do is get the data from the firebase, anyone could help me?

Comment: are you gettting any error

Comment: read the comment pls

Comment: This is async flow, you cannot get the value synchronously.

Comment: then how to fix it ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It appears you're using an async method which means the value is not available until execution gets inside the callback handler. Have you tried this?

```
var relative = af.database.object('users/user75ECZOiNtxZwYoezaXmYA9YwPm53', { preserveSnapshot: true });

relative.subscribe(snapshot => {
    this.usedBasicProfile = snapshot;
    console.log(this.usedBasicProfile);
});
```

Comment: I am sorry, your code is still not work for me, but thanks for your help

Comment: What does it print out? Still undefined? Does `snapshot` have an actual value?

Comment: yes, bro, I am afraid it is still undefined, while the console.log(snapshot) appear to be like this  "V {A: O, V: U, g: rc}"  , anyway thanks for your help

Comment: So you assign the value of `snapshot` to `this.usedBasicProfile` but by the very next line somehow the value is gone? In a single threaded environment like javascript that's hard to understand. Not sure what's going on there.

Comment: this second line in your the curly braces worked actually with value , but outside the curly braces, this.usedBasicProfile is undefined, maybe I misunderstand your meaning, sorry.

Comment: @Steveeeeee Did you read the link echonax gave you? You get your answer there, why it is undefined outside the callback. Please also consider accepting the duplicate, because it's an exact duplicate of that question ;)